# Regular win8 app failing Direct3D Cert Kit

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, direct3d

I'm currently developing a C# & XAML app using SQLite and Telerik's chart control. When I try to run a certification using the WACK kit, I get the error captured below. However, I have no idea why I get this error, as I'm not using Direct3D as far as I know, and I've only created a totally normal Store application in Visual Studio, nothing related to gaming.. Help? :)

I guess it's also worth mentioning that the app will run on X86 only, not ARM yet.

I've also tried making a new basic project in Visual Studio, and it gets the same error even though the project is "empty":
[image]

Anyone knows why? I've also unplugged my second monitor, as I saw someone saying that it would help - it didn't, sadly.

Comment: which version of the WACK are you using ? I ran into this issue recently I upgraded my WACK and it worked (same circonstences as yours no gaming just a 'standard app').

Comment: Thanks, @Aymeric. I simply had to run the same check on another computer with more HDD space available (yep, it's true).

Comment: Ok :s how strange is that, right? ^^